# Writing out heartbeat sound

Tags: onomatopoeia

Is it correct to write out the sound of a heart beat as lub dub or are there other variations that are also acceptable?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_sounds

Comment: *Lub dub* is the approximate 'sound' a normal heart makes when heard through a stethescope. It isn't nearly as clear when you just put your ear to the chest to listen. Anything you hear is fair game. boom boom, ba dum, whatever!

Comment: ba-dum, ba-dum, ba-dum-tsh

Comment: I suggest going to Edgar Allen Poe's "The Tell-tale Heart" and copying his description.

Comment: @Oldcat: That's Edgar **Allan** Poe, with an "a".

Answer (score 12):

There are different versions in different languages.
In english I have seen thump thump, ba boom, ba bump and lub-dub. In India, it is "dhakdhak." In Italian, it's  "tu tump."

Likewise, there are many others. Here is a link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cross-linguistic_onomatopoeias

open "human sounds" and then "heartbeat."

Comment: In Italian, songs about strong heartbeats are called [**bum bum**](http://www.wikitesti.com/Bum_bum_-_Irene_Grandi) read "*boom boom*" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRMTGUkHBMI.